# How can I find inspect element in mobile app while user name & password in the pop message

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webview, appium

When I click the button having text is "Login with facebook" then a dialog box us open then we need to enter the username and password.How can I write script in **selenium for appium android.**

How can I inspect the element and how can I switch to pop screen then type

Currently I am using this one but its not working

```
By webView = By.className("android.webkit.WebView");
driver.findElement(By.id("m_login_email")).sendKeys("gfjkjkjk@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use android UI automatorviewer to find the elements and use the below code 
hope it will works!

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("UiSelector().text(\"Continue with Facebook\")").click();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      driver.findElement(By.id("m_login_email")).sendKeys("yourfb id");
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      driver.findElement(By.id("m_login_password")).sendKeys("password");
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_5")).click();
```